# Some doubt about root password

Tags: security, lamp

I was looking for installing a LAMP in my personal PC but I can't create folders in `/var/www` so i run this little script in my console:

```
sudo passwd -l root
```

And I don't know if this an issue security in my system. If is, what I'll do to solve this ?

Comment: can you `sudo touch filename.php`?

Answer (score 4):

`sudo passwd -l root` is the command you run if you want to disable direct root login. It is a good thing. **You do not want to enable root login.** (By this I mean it's impossible to log in from a proper login prompt or directly over SSH)

You can still "get root" by running `sudo su` from your normal user (assuming they're in the `admin`/`sudo` group), or you can run single commands as root by prepending them with `sudo`.

---

Anyway, `/var/www` is in the `www-data` group so if you run:

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data $USER  # add the user to the www-data group
sudo sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www  # allow the group to write
```

After you log out an in again, you should be able to write in `/var/www`

Comment: A little addendum to your answer, locking a password (for example the password of the root account) does not necessarily completely lock the account. With 'sudo passwd -l root' you disable the possibility to log in as 'root' *with a password*. But it may still by possible to log in as 'root' by other means of authentication, for example a public key.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck Hmm a fair point but `sshd` has `PermitRootLogin no` by default.

Comment: To my knowledge at least the Ubuntu packages of sshd have `PermitRootLogin yes` by default. I'm not sure about upstream sshd. I installed sshd on my desktop machine running Quantal (restricted to IPs from my local network), so I can ssh in from my laptop. On this installation of sshd I didn't change `PermitRootLogin` and it is set to `yes`. 

Additionally, the difference I pointed out applies to any user account, not just "root" ;) And AFAIK sshd accepts authorization by password and pubkey by default.

But we're getting quite far from the original question ;)

Comment: The last I checked this was set to "no" in a default setup, @HenningKockerbeck.  Lemme check the defaults.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck confirmed: `PermitRootLogin no` is configured in NORMAL installations.  VM images, VPS images, etc. may have that configured differently, but the default is `no` on the package.

Comment: @TheLordofTime Interesting, I was quite sure that I didn't change that setting at the sshd on my desktop system, and it has `PermitRootLogin yes`. Ah, well, seems I remembered wrong.